# Failed javascript in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, function, cordova, apk

I am trying to crate an application with phonegap. In this code the 'window.location.href..' works very fine in browsers. But in the apk, I'll created with phonegap it doesn't work.

For testing i created one seperate js funktion, it will be triggered by an onclick on the button.
But this also do not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        if (!(localStorage.getItem('session_id') && localStorage.getItem('user_id'))) {
            window.location.href="login.html";
        }

        function test() {
            window.location.href="menu.html";
        }

        function (){
            $.ajax ({
                url:'http://marcelkipp.com/quizapp/userinfo.php?user_id='+localStorage.getItem('user_id'),
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'get',
                cache: false,
                success:function(data) {
                    console.log('JSON erfolgreich ausgelesen!');
                    var category = data.category_title;
                    if (category==null) category = "Keine Kategorie gewählt";
                    localStorage.setItem('username', data.username);
                    localStorage.setItem('role', data.role);
                    localStorage.setItem('points', data.points);
                    localStorage.setItem('total_questions',data.number_pq);
                    localStorage.setItem('category_title',data.category_title);
                    window.location.href="menu.html";
                }
                error:function(data) {
                    console.log('json failed');
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="spinner">
          <div class="rect1"></div>
          <div class="rect2"></div>
          <div class="rect3"></div>
          <div class="rect4"></div>
          <div class="rect5"></div>
        </div>
        <button onclick="test()">woohoo</button>
        <div style="margin:0px auto;text-align:center;color:#ffffff;">loading userdata</div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
window.location.replace("menu.html");
```